# Android Eclipse Proguard fail - can't build project, no R.java generated

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

Ok, new to Android development. I'm using eclipse and starting a new project in accordance with the Android tutorials. When I create the project it says: proguard.cfg no such file or directory and the gen folder is empty, and the project has no default.properties.

Some suggestions say that the proguard thing can be solved by modifying default.properties but as I say this is not there in the project to begin with.

Others say to regenerate R.java I should delete the gen folder and rebuild (or do a clean). This does nothing. I am going mad trying to get this to work. I'm trying to build against 2.1 (SDK 7)

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you correctly installed the ADT plugin and SDK for Eclipse?

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If problem still persist..
Just reinstall JAVA and ANDROID in the root directory instead of under their default paths in program files.

Answer (score 0):

Clean install of Android SDK helped me with same problem. Downloaded [starter package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), extracted to different (than existing one) directory, changed SDK directory to new one and redownloaded everything - problem solved!